# Swift removeFromSuperview does not trigger viewWillAppear

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I have a view controller that has a button. when that button is tapped the second vc gets added over the first view controller. When i tap a button on the 2nd vc it removes from superview....but that does not trigger the viewwillappear where my methods are called. Therefore a few things arent working like reloading the tableview...

can somebody explain how to get this to work?
Thanks

**Update 1 Code Added**

how i add the 2nd VC

```
let blurEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffectStyle.Dark))

    if !UIAccessibilityIsReduceTransparencyEnabled()
    {
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()

        blurEffectView.frame = self.view.bounds
        blurEffectView.autoresizingMask = [.FlexibleWidth, .FlexibleHeight]
        blurEffectView.alpha = 0
    }
    newView.view.alpha = 0.0

    self.view.addSubview(blurEffectView)
    self.view.addSubview(newView.view)

    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.8){

        self.newView.view.alpha = 1
        self.blurEffectView.alpha = 1
    }
```

How i remove 2nd VC

```
 ViewController().blurEffectView.removeFromSuperview()
```

Comment: Could you post some code? How do you add the second vc?

Comment: code added, sorry about that

Answer (score 2):

The issue with your code is that you do not push a new UIViewController, you just add a UIView on top of it. ViewWillAppear will only trigger when the UIViewController is not the one on top of the stack and the one on top gets removed (using dismiss).

```
self.view.addSubview(blurEffectView)
self.view.addSubview(newView.view)
```

These lines just add UIViews as subviews to your current UIViewController.view so the active UIViewController is still the one you're in, which means that removing the subviews won't call any of the callback methods for the UIViewController. I believe you'd be better off calling your methods before you do `ViewController().blurEffectView.removeFromSuperview()`

I might misunderstand though since this is just a snippet of code and I don't even know what kind of function it lies in. If you need further help it would be easier if you could upload a sample project.